# how to detect javascript features on Android 1.5

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to write a code that can run on Android 1.5 and 2.0.1, but I have issues with the javascript engine used on Android 1.5.

`alert(localStorage);` just hang on v1.5 while on v2.0.1 it alerts correctly.

is there an unblocking way to do it or to detect the version of Android with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the Android version from `navigator.userAgent` though

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this,

```
if(window.localStorage) {
    alert(localStorage);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is possible to overload the alert handler in a WebView. I would write my own based on an alert dialog and see if that works better than the default.

Comment: Specifically, this is handled by `WebChromeClient` and `onJsAlert()`.

Comment: the problem is not with Alert, but the general "javascript hang" when I try to use an unsupported javascript function.